# Select first word from each line in multiple lines with Vim

Tags: vim

I would like to copy the first words of multiple lines.

Example of code :

```
apiKey := fmt.Sprintf("&apiKey=%s", args.ApiKey)
maxCount := fmt.Sprintf("&maxCount=%d", args.MaxCount)
id := fmt.Sprintf("&id=%s", args.Id)
userid := fmt.Sprintf("&userid=%s", args.Userid)
requestFields := fmt.Sprintf("&requestFields=%s", args.RequestFields)
```

I would like to have this in my clipboard :

```
apiKey
maxCount
id
userid
requestFields
```

I tried with ctrl-v and after e, but it copies like on the image :
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could append every first word to an empty register (let's say `q`) using

```
:'<,'>norm! "Qyiw
```

That is, in every line of the visual selection, execute the `"Qyiw` sequence of `normal` commands to append (the first) "inner word" to the `q` register.

You need to have `>` in `cpoptions` for the newline to be added in between yanks (`:set cpoptions+=>`), otherwise the words will be concatenated on a single line.

If you want to quickly empty a register you can use `qqq` in normal mode (or `qaq` to empty register `a`).

Note: the unnamed register (`""`) will also contain what you want at the end of the operation, so you don't need to `"qp` to paste it, `p` will do.

Comment: Awesome :)! But it copies the last word twice : 
        followedTopics
 apiKey
 maxCount
 id
 userid
 requestFields
 requestFieldsAON
 referrer
 browsingHistory
 useActivity
 useInventory
 followedUsers
 followedTopics. Any idea why?

Comment: My bad it was because my register wasn't empty

Comment: Oh but when I paste it, it creates newlines whereas when I yank from a select column, it paste without creating new lines.. is there a way to do that?

Comment: @GermainGum: Can't think of a way to do that easily. You *could* paste the content of the register, visual-block select & yank it, undo and then paste that, I guess. Pretty tedious if you do that manipulation a lot though (quite easy to have a mapping that does all of this though).

Comment: One thing you could use is `setreg`. You can check `:help` for details, but it allows you to set a register's value to something and change its type, if you need to. In this case, you can `setreg('q', @q, 'b')`. This doesn't change the `q` register's value, but changes its type to "b", which is visual block mode. Mind you, in my tests, there's also one blank line at the top, but that one you'd have to remove manually, maybe with a `substitute()`.

Comment: If you are using ideavim, you won't be able to do this as it doesn't support `normal` or `norm` command yet.

Answer (score 2):

I think the chosen answer is a really good one, the idea of appending matches to registers can be pretty useful in other scenarios as well.

That said, an alternative way to get this done might be to align the right-hand side first, do the copying and then undo the alignment. You can use a tool like [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular), [Align](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Align) or [easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align).

With tabular, marking the area and executing `:Tab/:` would result in this:

```
apiKey        : = fmt.Sprintf("&apiKey=%s", args.ApiKey)
maxCount      : = fmt.Sprintf("&maxCount=%d", args.MaxCount)
id            : = fmt.Sprintf("&id=%s", args.Id)
userid        : = fmt.Sprintf("&userid=%s", args.Userid)
requestFields : = fmt.Sprintf("&requestFields=%s", args.RequestFields)
```

You can now use visual block mode to select the first part, and then use `u` to undo the alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Relying on the external `cut` program:

```
:'<,'>!cut -d' ' -f1
```